# How do I select an iframe by the src attribute using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

My code:

HTML:

```
<iframe src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" width="400" height="400"></iframe>
```

JS:

```
$("iframe[scr*='http://lorempixel.com/400/400/']").css("border", "3px solid blue");
```

Jsfiddle:

[Link to JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eNz4a/1/)

Can seem to select the iframe via its source attribute.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: [This][1] should answer your question.




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752857/jquery-select-img-with-src

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Solution

You have a typo, The correct attribute you should be referencing is `src` whereas your query is searching for an attribute named `scr` which doesn't exist.

so instead of

```
$("iframe[scr*='http://lorempixel.com/400/400/']").css("border", "3px solid blue");
```

you should have

```
$("iframe[src*='http://lorempixel.com/400/400/']").css("border", "3px solid blue");
```

---

### Example

### > [here's a jsfiddle which shows this typo corrected](http://jsfiddle.net/d439h/)

---

**Reference:**

- http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/img/src

Comment: Thank You. I just couldn't see it. Lucky I cut n paste the code.

Comment: @user2079630 if the answer i gave helped you out, please mark it as the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

You misspelled "src" in the jQuery selector. It is currently `scr`, it should be `src`.
Fixed code:

```
$("iframe[src*='http://lorempixel.com/400/400/']").css("border", "3px solid blue");
```

And fixed JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Je3SG/1/

Comment: I was first to answer, by about 30 seconds! :P