# How to find Xpath for an image based on its src using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I have a javascript function to find the xpath of elements on a webpage. However, I need to build the xpath based on 'src' only for images.

```
function getPathTo(element) {
   if (element.id!=='')
       return './/*[@id=\"'+ element.id +'\"]';
   if (element===document.body)
       return element.tagName;
   var ix= 0;
   var siblings= element.parentNode.childNodes;
   for (var i= 0; i<siblings.length; i++) {
       var sibling= siblings[i];
       if (sibling===element)
           return getPathTo(element.parentNode)+'/'+element.tagName+'['+(ix+1)+']';
       if (sibling.nodeType===1 && sibling.tagName===element.tagName)
           ix++;
   }
}
```

How can I tweak this code to get xpath for images based on 'src'? Please help.

Comment: It isn't clear at all what your codes do and what you want it to do. *"I need to build the xpath based on 'src' only for images"*, could you elaborate more and provide some example?

Comment: Well, call this function only with the `element` parameter that you want. First, select the image based on src ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752857/jquery-select-img-with-src ) and then call that function with it as a parameter.

Comment: @har07, I need to generate xpath for image. The above function receives element object as parameter and build the xpath for it. (Ex: .//*[@id="abc"])
Now, if the selected element in image, I need to generate the xpath something like ".//*[@src="abc.png"]

Comment: @Cristy, I'm actually looking for vice versa. I'm not giving the xpath and highlighting the element. Instead, I click on the element and generate xpath using the above mentioned function

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj That's what I said !? Give the element that you want and generate the xpath by calling `getPathTo(yourImageElement)`. If you want `src` instead of `id`, then you have to change your function accordingly.

Comment: @Cristy, I'm new to javascript. I got this piece of code from somewhere. However, I tried doing like this, but doesn't work.
if(element.tagName==img)        
return './/*[@src='+element.src+']';

Comment: `if(element.tagName=='img')` . `img` is a string, so it has to be between quotes.